# Override viewForAnnotation method in iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios4, mkmapview

I want to override the `viewForAnnotation` method provided by the delegate.

I want to pass 1 more argument, `type`, so that I can change the color of pins according to the kind of annotation.

For ex: I would want it to be `viewForAnnotation:type:`.

Any help ?

Comment: I am not sure but I think you need to create custom class which is a sub-class of MKMapView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to "override"/replace the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method.

Instead, add whatever properties you need to your class that implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol (the one you instantiate to pass to the `addAnnotation` method).

Then in the standard `viewForAnnotation` method, you can access your custom properties in the `annotation` parameter that is passed.  You should first check if the annotation's class is your custom class and then cast it before trying to reference the custom properties.

If you're using the pre-defined `MKPointAnnotation` class for your annotations, you'll have to switch to your own custom class.

Comment: Thats exactly what I ended up doing! I created a subclass of MKPointAnnotation, and added whatever new values I wanted there.. :)